# How to Change font type in WinCe Device

Tags: fonts, windows-ce, font-size

I am working on WinCE Device,working on GDI in that i am trying to change the font type, i have enabled the all font types in catalog items(Arial,Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Georgia,Tahoma,Times New Roman,Trebuchet MS,Veradana),i want to use that fonts but those are not working,device is working with default font only,

The code i am using is given below...

```
void CreateText ()
{
// First, clear all fields.
memset (&logfont, 0, sizeof (logfont));

// Create a GDI Times New Roman font.
logfont.lfHeight = 20;
logfont.lfWidth = 0; 
logfont.lfEscapement = 0;
logfont.lfOrientation = 0;
logfont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
logfont.lfItalic = TRUE;//FALSE;
logfont.lfUnderline = FALSE;
logfont.lfStrikeOut = FALSE;
logfont.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
logfont.lfOutPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;    
logfont.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
logfont.lfQuality = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
logfont.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
_tcsncpy (logfont.lfFaceName, TEXT("Arial"), LF_FACESIZE);  //Comic Sans MS 
logfont.lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE-1] = TEXT('\0');  // Ensure null termination
hfontTimes = CreateFontIndirect (&logfont);
//CreatePointFontIndirect(&logfont);
if (!hfontTimes)   {
    // CreateFontIndirect failed. Insert code here for error
    // handling.
    printf("\n CreateFontIndirect failed... ");
}

//SendMessage(NULL,WM_SETREDRAW,(WPARAM)TRUE,NULL);

}

void initiateText ()
{
// Get a GDI DC onto the backbuffer, where you will render the text.
hdcSurface = GetDC (NULL);

// Select the font into the DC.
hfontSave = (HFONT) SelectObject (hdcSurface, hfontTimes);

// Set the background mode to transparent, so there is no
// rectangle behind the text.
SetBkMode (hdcSurface, TRANSPARENT);
}


void printText (HDC      hdcSurface, 
                int      screen_x,
                int      screen_y,
                LPTSTR   lpszText,
                COLORREF color)
{
int bReturn;

// Set text color.
SetTextColor (hdcSurface, color);

bReturn = ExtTextOut (hdcSurface,
                      screen_x,
                      screen_y,
                      0,                  // No flags set
                      NULL,               // No clipping rectangle
                      lpszText,           // String to display
                      lstrlen (lpszText), // Number of characters
                      NULL);              // Use default spacing.
}
```

as explained above selected font is not displaying on screen,looking for your suggestions.

Comment: `i want to use that fonts but those are not working,device is working with default font only,` What you mean by this?? How you tested?? If you want to test whether fonts are added, open Word Editor and see dropdown menu for "fonts".. Like this only you have tested??

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to determine if the Fonts are actually in the system and registered.  Calling [`EnumFontFamilies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911445.aspx) will tell you what the OS actually sees, along with the exact names you'll need to use for the `lfFaceName` parameter.

**EDIT**

If the fonts do not show up when you enumerate, then that tells me they are not in the OS.  There could be any number of reasons why they didn't get into the OS.  Take a look in the `BUILDRELDIR` for the OS image and see if they are there.  If they are, then it sounds like you didn't `makeimg` to get them into the actual OS.  Also check `ce.bib` to see if the build system was actually told to include them (some project or platform file could have excluded them explicitly).

A final, brute-force way would be to make sure the font files are on the device and then call `AddFontResource` when your app starts.

Comment: i Used EnumFontFamilies() function, in that default font it is giving "Arial" only,but as enabled the all fonts in catalog items it need to show the other fonts also but remaining fonts are not giving what could be the wrong.

Comment: i have checked in OS image and ce.bib file in both the places fonts are present,i have tried AddFontResource() it is giving error like INVALID_DATA

Comment: thanks for your response,got the solution for problem,after increasing size of program memory everything working as expected.